# How to initialize a base member variable with customized virtual function in the subclass

Tags: c++, design-patterns

The constructor of class StructComponent takes a different logic to initialize its member variables based on the type of the pass-in object of info. Here I use casting to convert the pass-in parameter to right subclass object.

```
class StructComponent
{
public:
    StructComponent(const ClassA& info)
    {
        if (info.getType() == CLASS_B)
        {
            const ClassC& classC = dynamic_cast<const ClassC&> info;
            ...
            apply a different logic for ClassB and init member accordingly
        } else if (info.getType() == CLASS_C) {
            apply a different logic for others
            ...
        } else {
                    apply default
            }
    }
}

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(...)
    {
        m_shp = CreateStructComponent();
    }   
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> CreateStructComponent()
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> (new StructComponent(*this));     
    }

    ...
    int getType() const { return CLASS_A; }

protected:
    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> m_shp;
}

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    ...

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> CreateStructComponent()
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> (new StructComponent(*this));     
    }   
    ...
    int getType() const { return CLASS_B; } 
}

class ClassC : public ClassA
{
public:
    ...

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> CreateStructComponent()
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> (new StructComponent(*this));     
    }   
    ...
    int getType() const { return CLASS_C; } 
}
```

Q1> Is the code correct ignore the potential design issue?

Q2> Assuem all subclass of ClassA has the same implementation body of the function CreateStructComponent.
Is there a way that I can save space not to repeatedly do the same code as follows:

```
return boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> (new StructComponent(*this));
```

Q3> Is there a better design that I can use? For example, is there a way that I can ignore casting in the 
StructComponent?

Comment: Q2) Yes. Q1/3) You shouldn't have to know the concrete type of your object. Give `ClassA` a suitable virtual initialization function (possibly accepting a `StructComponent&`) and just call that.

Comment: @KerrekSB, in the current design StructComponent does need to know the type of the passed-in in order to make correct initialization. I will update my code and make it clear.

Comment: I don't see why you have to redefine `CreateStructComponent` at all in the derived classes, as all of them are identical.

Comment: @DanielKO, you are right. In the real code, each one is different. The reason I put this way is to confirm my guess of Q2.

Comment: Also, there's a general design principle: Make non-leaf classes abstract. That obviates the need for repeated "create" functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, it's not correct, at least, it doesn't do what you probably expect. It calls a virtual function in the constructor of `ClassA`, which will always call `ClassA::CreateStructComponent()` instead of calling the overriding function in the derived class, because when the `ClassA` constructor runs that dynamic type is `ClassA`.  For the same reason, in the constructor for `StructComponent` the `getType()` call will always resolve to `ClassA::getType()`.

2) There are lots of ways to solve that problem. You could put the code in a template, so it depends on the type, or you could just get rid of the need to duplicate the code, by doing the initialization in a different place.

3) Why not simply give `StructComponent` overloaded constructors, one taking `ClassB`, one taking `ClassC` and another taking `ClassA`?

Then again, a better solution would probably be to get rid of the `StructComponent` constructor and have `ClassA`, `ClassB`, or `ClassC` do the initialization explicitly, so that each type initializes it how it wants it done.  If the initialization depends on the type that creates it, the initialization doesn't belong in the `StructComponent` constructor.  Currently you have a circular dependency, `StructComponent` needs to know about all the types that use it, and all the types that use it need to know about `StructComponent`. That's usually a sign of a problem with the design, all the classes are tightly coupled to each other.  It would be better if `StrictComponent` knew nothing about the other types.

Anyway, here's one possible solution, showing a way to pass the correct type to the `StructComponent` without duplicating code, but I don't think this is a good design.  Note that the `Structcomponent` constructor is passed NULL, so it can do different things based on the type, but **cannot** access the objects it is passed.

```
class StructComponent
{
public:
    explicit StructComponent(const ClassA*)
    { /* something */ }

    explicit StructComponent(const ClassB*)
    { /* something else */ }

    explicit StructComponent(const ClassC*)
    { /* something completely different */ }
};

class Base
{
protected:
  template<typename T>
    explicit
    Base(const T*)
    : m_shp( boost::make_shared<StructComponent>((T*)NULL) )
    { }

    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> m_shp;
};

class ClassA : virtual public Base
{
public:
    ClassA() : Base(this) { }
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB() : Base(this) { }
};

class ClassC : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassC() : Base(this) { }
};
```

Here's another, completely-different approach without virtual base hacks, still removing duplicated code, and allowing `StructComponent` to access the objects passed to it (which I maintain is a bad idea):

```
class StructComponent
{
public:
    explicit StructComponent(const ClassA& a)
    { /* something */ }

    explicit StructComponent(const ClassB& b)
    { /* something else */ }

    explicit StructComponent(const ClassC& c)
    { /* something completely different */ }
};

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA() : m_shp( create(*this) ) { }

protected:
    struct no_init { };

    explicit
    ClassA(no_init)
    : m_shp()
    { }

    template<typename T>
      boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> create(const T& t)
      { return boost::make_shared<StructComponent>(t); }

    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> m_shp;
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB()
    : ClassA(no_init())
    { m_shp = create(*this); }
};

class ClassC : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassC()
    : ClassA(no_init())
    { m_shp = create(*this); }
};
```

And here's yet another choice, this time without the circular dependencies, moving the different initialization code where it belongs:

```
struct StructComponent
{
  StructComponent() { /* minimum init */ }
};

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA() : m_shp( createA() ) { }

protected:
    struct no_init { };

    explicit
    ClassA(no_init)
    : m_shp()
    { }

    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> createA()
    {
      // something
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> m_shp;
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB()
    : ClassA(no_init())
    { m_shp = createB(); }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> createB()
    {
      // something else
    }
};

class ClassC : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassC()
    : ClassA(no_init())
    { m_shp = createC(); }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<StructComponent> createC()
    {
      // something completely different
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

During execution of the constructor of class `A`, the type of the object is `A`.  The base implementation will therefore always be called.  You can therefore save the trouble of retyping the implementation.

This code is incorrectly designed; and incorrectly designed code is never correct, at least in the usual meaning of the word "correct".

There is no reason why you should use a constructor for initialization if the C++ rules don't work well for you.  Simply make it a method, call the thing `Initialize`, and you can call any virtual methods from `Initialize` that you desire, with the effects you seem to expect.